# What is my DAC clocking frequency for this STM32 board?

Tags: stm32, clock, dac

I'm trying to figure out the exact clocking frequency of the DACs for [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) board.
Here is the clock config:

[image]

And the code section for the DAC initilaztion:

```
static void MX_DAC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 1 */
  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac.Instance = DAC;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_NONE;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** DAC channel OUT2 config
  */
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC_Init 2 */

}
```

and for the system clock config:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 320;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Are the above enough to quantify the clocking freq of the DACs? And how to calculate it?

Comment: What do you mean by DAC clocking and why do you need this information? You may have an X-Y problem, so what made you ask this question?

Comment: For a device input, I need clocking frequency higher than 20kS/s. To prevent antialiasing.

Comment: clocking frequency I mean similar to sampling freq for an ADC. Here meaning how many samples DAC outputs per second.

Comment: The DAC's output 'sample rate' depends on how fast you feed new sample values to it. So how are you sending output data valued to your DAC? If you want a consistent sample rate you would typically set up a timer and either use the timer interrupt handler to send a new value to the DAC, or use the timer to trigger a DMA operation to read from a buffer and write to the DAC. As Ilya mentions, the device datasheet tells you what the maximum rate is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference manual, page 183. DAC clock enable is in RCC_APB1ENR, therefore it must be clocked by default from APB1 clock (PCLK1).

Further down on page 207 we see register RCC_DCKCFGR, where some peripherals can choose their clock source. There is no clock source switching for DAC. So there is only one and only source. APB1 clock. The frequency must therefore be 20MHz in your case.

[image]

Also, in DAC registers themselves there is nothing related to clocks.

EDIT:

Sampling rate is 1Msps (mega-sample per second) as stated in the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf) on page 141.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to read this value. I would like to see that in while loop-

Comment: if (RCC->APB1ENR & RCC_APB1ENR_DACEN) {if DAC activated} else {if not activated}. Single &, bitwise AND. Not DAC activated. DAC supplied with clock. You need to activate it separately in DAC registers

Comment: I mean the value of the DAC clock. Here I mean how many samples DAC outputs per second.

Comment: How many samples it outputs per second is a completely different matter. Requires detailed reading of DAC section of the reference manual. I suggest you take a look, it's not all terrible.

Comment: Thats what I was asking actually. Is there a way to figure it out?

Comment: I thought it outputs per clock.

Comment: Edited in the sampling rate

Comment: Great thanks a lot, the DAC sampling rate is beyond what I need,

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected. You have at least three misconceptions.

The sampling rate at which you want to send samples has nothing to do with at what rate the DAC peripheral clock or bus clock is running.

And you need to prevent aliasing, not antialiasing. And since this is a DAC and not an ADC you actually don't have aliasing to begin with as the DAC has a zero-order hold output. You need external filter to get rid of the generated images.

Comment: I see thanks for corrections. And what do you mean by "generated images"?

Comment: The images are the reason why you need a reconstruction filter after the zero-order-hold DAC, to convert square-wave steps to reconstruct smooth analog signal.